# Unzipped an email csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am in the process of migrating an app that ingests an email and extracts the zip file attachment.  This is working in python2, and looks like:

```
import email
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

def get_email_csv(mail):
    payload = None
    if mail.is_multipart():
        for part in mail.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and 
               part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None and 
               'attachment' in part.get('Content-Disposition'):              
                payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                break
    if payload is not None:
        content = StringIO(payload)
        input_zip=ZipFile(content)
        for name in input_zip.namelist():
             unzipped = input_zip.read(name)
        return unzipped
```

However I am having an issue migrating this to python3.  Here is the code I have for this:

```
import email
from io import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

def get_email_csv(mail):
    payload = None
    if mail.is_multipart():
        for part in mail.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and 
               part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None and 
               'attachment' in part.get('Content-Disposition'):              
                payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                break
    if payload is not None:
        content = StringIO(payload.decode('latin1'))
        input_zip=ZipFile(content)
        for name in input_zip.namelist():
             unzipped = input_zip.read(name)
        return unzipped
```

This seems to be causing an exception `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`. Do I have to do more than decode the payload in python3, is there some other difference/step that I need to do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding the binary into Unicode is wrong. You want the actual `bytes` (and hence `BytesIO`).

```py
import email
from io import BytesIO  # not StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

def get_email_csv(mail):
    payload = None
    if mail.is_multipart():
        for part in mail.walk():   # Note backslash syntax fixes v
            if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and \
               part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None and \
               'attachment' in part.get('Content-Disposition'):              
                payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                break
    if payload is not None:
        content = BytesIO(payload)  # BytesIO -> no decode()
        input_zip=ZipFile(content)
        for name in input_zip.namelist():
             unzipped = input_zip.read(name)
        return unzipped
```

I would probably take out the check for a `Content-Disposition:`; this header is not strictly necessary, and some clients probably leave it out. A binary attachment would have a default disposition of `'attachment'` anyway (it's hard to imagine what `'inline'` would even mean here).